# Gravar em duas tabelas diferentes usando a mesma View

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5

Estou fazendo um cadastro de fornecedores, e preciso gravá-lo em uma tabela e o seu endereço em outra. Utilizo uma única view *fornecedores.blade* para preencher todos os dados.Como posso separar esses dados para gravá-los em suas respectivas tabelas?

**Tabela Fornecedores:**

```
id          | int
nome        | varchar
endereco_id | int
```

**Tabela Endereço:**

```
id          | int
logradouro  | varchar
bairro      | varchar
cep         | int
```

**Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    Fornecedor::create($input);
    return redirect('fornecedores');
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function endereco() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Endereco', 'id', 'endereco_id');
}
```

Comment: O problema é pegar o `id` do endereço e gravar no fornecedor?

Comment: @rray, também. Todos os dados são preenchidos na view fornecedor. A action desse form vai pro controller de fornecedores. Quero separar os dados pessoais e o endereço, gravar cada um em sua respectiva tabela e então fazer o relacionamento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Resolvido:**
>   Dentro do método `store()` do FornecedorController eu separei os campos para cada tabela, ao invés de usar `$request->all()`.

**FornecedorController**:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $endereco = new Endereco();
    $endereco->logradouro = $request->get('logradouro');
    $endereco->numero = $request->get('bairro');
    $endereco->numero = $request->get('cep');
    $endereco->save();
    $endereco_id= $endereco->id;

    $fornecedor = new Fornecedor();
    $fornecedor->cnpj = $request->get('cnpj');
    $fornecedor->razao_social = $request->get('razao_social');
    $fornecedor->endereco_id = $endereco_id;
    $fornecedor->save();

    return redirect('view');
}
```

Não sei se é a melhor forma (boa prática) de fazer isso, mas resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Fala amigo, tudo bom? Vamos lá!

Aparentimente o caso é de relacionamento hasOne... como assim?

A sua tabela fornecedores trabalha com relacionamento n:1 para endereços.

Corrigindo que no seu model você definiu como hasMany, que tradução livre é "contém vários". Ou seja, `fornecedores contém vários endereços`. Que conforme seu schema não é bem assim, nele o fornecedor contém só UM endereço, pois trabalha com FK direta para endereços.

O eloquent da alternativas para trabalhar com relacionamentos, de certa forma praticamente mamão com açúcar.

```
$fornecedor = new Fornecedor();
$fornecedor->cnpj = $request->get('cnpj');
$fornecedor->razao_social = $request->get('razao_social');
$fornecedor->endereco->logradouro = $request->get('logradouro');
$fornecedor->endereco->bairro = $request->get('bairro');
$fornecedor->endereco->cep = $request->get('cep');
$fornecedor->push();
```

Neste exemplo irá ocorrer o "push". Ao salvar o fornecedor ele irá salvar o endereço e já fazer a relação para você.

Você pode conferir no manual este método: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

Lembrando que você precisa fazer a relação de: `fornecedores belongsTo enderecos`

O push ele verifica toda relação e efetua os comandos, caso não venha a te agradar o uso dela, você poderá optar pela `associate`.

Bom, dúvidas da um toque!

Comment: Obrigado, @juniorb2ss. Vou testar hoje a noite. Eu imaginei que existisse uma fórmula "mágica" pra fazer isso, mas como eu estava com um pouco de pressa, resolvi fazer manualmente mesmo. Tenho outros relacionamentos parecidos e tentarei usar dessa forma.

Comment: @buback aaah tem sim, eloquent é cheio de métodos mágicos, ainda mais para trabalhos com relacionamentos. Único problema é que algumas coisas as querys não são tão performáticas :(

Comment: tentei fazer o que disse em outro exemplo. Usando o push(). Mas não funcionou. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86714/relacionamento-nn-no-laravel-n%C3%A3o-grava-atributos-do-objeto