# Relacionamento N:N no Laravel não grava atributos do objeto

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5

Minhas tabelas têm, resumidamente, a seguinte estrutura:

**atas:**

```
id | vigencia
```

**produtos:**

```
id | nome | descricao
```

**ata_produto:**

```
ata_id | produto_id | vlr_produto | qtd_produto
```

O mesmo produto pode ter valor diferente dependendo da ata, então no cadastro do produto não tem preço. Ele só é definido na hora que eu o insiro em uma ata.
Para isso preciso gravar o `id` do produto e da ata, além da quantidade e valor de cada produto.

O problema está aí, **consigo relacionar os produtos às atas**, mas não são gravados o preço e a quantidade.

**Model - Produto:**

```
public function atas() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ata')->withPivot('vlr_produto', 'qtd_produto');
}
```

**Model - Ata:**

```
public function produtos() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Produto')->withPivot('vlr_produto', 'qtd_produto');
}
```

**AtaController:**

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->all();
    $produtos      = (array)array_get($input, 'produto_id');
    $quantidades   = (array)array_get($input, 'qtd_produto');
    $valores       = (array)array_get($input, 'vlr_produto');

    $ata = Ata::create($input);
    $ata->produtos()->sync($produtos, $quantidades, $valores);

    return redirect('admin/atas');
}
```

Como eu disse, o relacionamento funciona. Não sei como fazer gravar, além do `produto_id` e `ata_id`, o `vlr_produto` e a `qtd_produto`.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Laravel Eloquent provê, basicamente, duas maneiras para trabalhar com relacionamento *vários para vários* (N:N).

A primeira é *anexar* e *separar* manualmente. Para isso utilize `attach` e `detach`.

A segunda é construir relacionamento entre os modelos com `sync`.

Utilizando esse método você deve passar um array com o *id* e seus respectivos valores na tabela intermediária.

```
$produto_id = 1;
$valor = 10;
$quantidade = 10;

$attributes = [ 'vlr_produto' => $valor, 'qtd_produto' => $quantidade ];

$ata->produtos()->sync( $produto_id => $attributes );
```

Em caso de vários produtos:

```
$ata->produtos()->sync([ $produto_id => $attributes, 
                         $other_produto_id => $other_attributes ]);
```

**ATENÇÃO**

Quando utilizar o método `sync`:

> Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is complete, only the IDs in the array will exist in the intermediate table

[Laravel Eloquent Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)

Aparentemente, você não deseja remover outras relações de **atas** com **produtos** quando invoca esse método. Então, recomendo que utilize o `attach` para criar os relacionamentos.

Para isso, faça:

```
$attributes = [ 'vlr_produto' => $valor, 'qtd_produto' => $quantidade ];

$ata->produtos()->attach( $produto_id, $attributes );
```

Caso queira anexar vários **produtos** à **ata**, sugiro que faça um *loop*

```
$produtos = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

$valores = [ 
   1 => 10, 
   2 => 20, 
   3 => 30 
];

$quantidades = [ 
   1 => 10, 
   2 => 20, 
   3 => 30 
];

foreach ( $produtos as $index => $produto ) 
{
  // atributos do produto atual
  $attributes = [ 
     'vlr_produto' => $valores[ $index ], 
     'qtd_produto' => $quantidades[ $index ] 
  ];

  $ata->produtos()->attach( $produto, $attributes );
}
```

Essa é uma solução didática. Adapte-a de acordo com seus dados.

Salve o modelo ao final da operação

```
$ata->save();
```

Comment: pois é.. usando o sync(), mesmo da forma que sugeriu, não funcionou. Não sei como usar o attach para isso. Estou procurando e tentarei.

Comment: usei o $ata->produtos()->attach($produtos, $atributos); e funcionou se só estiver gravando um único produto, mas como um array. Dá erro. Estranho que a variável $produtos também é um array.

Comment: Usando o attach dessa forma retorna o erro: "preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array"

Comment: Vou atualizar a resposta para caso `attach` de vários produtos

Comment: Show! Funcionou. Só corrigi o foreach para usar o index, pois estava dando erro! Muito obrigado pela ajuda. :D